# UIView animation doesn't work

Tags: xcode, animation, uiview, uiimageview

The codes are very basic:

```
UIImageView *testView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
[self.view addSubview:testView];
[testView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:100
                 animations:^{testView.center =  CGPointMake(140,350);}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){NSLog(@"animation finished");
                 }
 ];
```

And somehow the animation just won't work. The image only shows up at the end position. The NSLog message does get displayed though.

**Does anyone know what may fail an animation?**

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know 100 sec is intended. Make sure you have button.png added to your project. I just copied your code and test with 10 sec and there was no problem.

Answer (score 2):

None of solutions provided up here actually work because he is probably calling his rotation code at a wrong place in code.

call it here and it will work

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view addSubview:testView];
```

after you add a subview..the UI isn't updated instantly..it takes a little time to refresh..However your animation is called before it can call it update..so the UI is updated only after animation completes.. i will suggest to call `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` before the animation .. or calling the animation after a little delay

Comment: Thank you, but I've tried both of your advices (setNeedsDisplay and animation delay), but it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the pasted code is your exact piece!! It has animation duration of 100 sec. Is that an intentional behavior ??

Also try changing the frame directly instead of center.

```
UIImageView *testView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 80)];
[self.view addSubview:testView];
[testView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{testView.frame =  CGRectMake(140,350,80,80);}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){NSLog(@"animation finished");
                 }
 ];
```

Comment: I just want to add that, per Apple's UIView documentation, animating with the UIView frame property will not work if the transform property is not equal to the identity transform. The default value of transform is the identity transform. When the transform property has some other value, it is necessary to animate with the center and bounds properties.

Answer (score 0):

**You are missing a few lines in the animation code.**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:100 
    delay:0 
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent 
    animations:^{
        testView.center =  CGPointMake(140,350);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){NSLog(@"animation finished")}
];
```

These animations are unique to `iOS 7` only, and are a much better solution than what you exemplified above.

You have probably long since answered this, but I hope this answer will help anyone else that stumbles across this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the QuartzCore framework:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```